# Is there a way to supress p-values in tbl_regression function in R?

Tags: r, regression, negative-binomial-distribution, probabilistic-programming

I want to make tables including exponentiated parameter coefficients with CIs, but not with p-values.
Right now i am using :

```
model <- glm(data=data, formula=outcome ~ categorical_variable)
tbl_regression(model,
    exponentiate = TRUE, 
    include="status_3cat")
```

This table includes p-values per parameter. Does anybody know how to eliminate the p-values?

Comment: Look at the code of `tbl_regression`, copy it, and modify it to not print p-values?

Comment: I tried looking at the cran-r document page and the vignette but could not find anything on supressing the p-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `tbl_regression` to a standard [gt](https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html) table and use the gt functions to hide a column, e.g.

```
library(gt)
tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE, include="status_3cat") %>% 
  as_gt() %>% 
  cols_hide("p.value")
```